# Using pgAdmin iii to manage a Django data base

Tags: django, postgresql, pgadmin

I am working on a Django project and I am wondering if it is possible to use the data I have on pgAdmin iii in my Django project? Can anyone point me to any tutorials or documentation that cover this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ultimatedjango.com/learn-django/lessons/configure-the-database/?trim=yes

This seems to be what i was looking for.